# I get "Expected an conditional expression and instead saw an assignment" even though it works

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I loaded the script `smoothscroll.js` to tampermonkey. The tampermonkey IDE showed alot of errors for that script, but the script worked perfectly fine nevertheless. However, I decided to fix these errors, which was very easy (missing semicolons, missing `()`, and some other issues).

However, I struggle how to fix the following error. There is a do-while loop with an assignment as conditional expression.

```js
function overflowingAncestor(el) {
  var elems = [];
  var rootScrollHeight = root.scrollHeight;
  do {
    var cached = cache[uniqueID(el)];
    if (cached) {
      return setCache(elems, cached);
    }
    elems.push(el);
    if (rootScrollHeight === el.scrollHeight) {
      if (!isFrame || root.clientHeight + 10 < rootScrollHeight) {
        return setCache(elems, document.body);
      }
    } else if (el.clientHeight + 10 < el.scrollHeight) {
      overflow = getComputedStyle(el, "").getPropertyValue("overflow-y");
      if (overflow === "scroll" || overflow === "auto") {
        return setCache(elems, el);
      }
    }
  } while (el = el.parentNode); //<--- Error
}
```

I thought the fix would be to simply replace `while (el = el.parentNode);` with `while (el == el.parentNode);` but the smoothscroll does not work anymore after applying this.

I know I could just let it like it is, but I try to understand why the error is thrown even though it is working?

If you would like to try it out live, then go to [this page](https://bs.to/andere-serien) and load the following script to your tampermonkey engine.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test
// @namespace    http://bs.to/
// @version      2.2
// @description  Test
// @author       Me
// @match        https://bs.to/andere-serien
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

//Smoothscroll.js
(function() {
  var defaultOptions = {
    frameRate: 300,
    animationTime: 1500,
    stepSize: 120,
    pulseAlgorithm: true,
    pulseScale: 8,
    pulseNormalize: 1,
    accelerationDelta: 20,
    accelerationMax: 1,
    keyboardSupport: true,
    arrowScroll: 50,
    touchpadSupport: true,
    fixedBackground: true,
    excluded: ""
  };
  var options = defaultOptions;
  var isExcluded = false;
  var isFrame = false;
  var direction = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  var initDone = false;
  var root = document.documentElement;
  var activeElement;
  var observer;
  var deltaBuffer = [120, 120, 120];
  var key = {
    left: 37,
    up: 38,
    right: 39,
    down: 40,
    spacebar: 32,
    pageup: 33,
    pagedown: 34,
    end: 35,
    home: 36
  };
  options = defaultOptions;

  function initTest() {
    var disableKeyboard = false;
    if (disableKeyboard) {
      removeEvent("keydown", keydown);
    }
    if (options.keyboardSupport && !disableKeyboard) {
      addEvent("keydown", keydown);
    }
  }

  function init() {
    if (!document.body)
      return;
    var body = document.body;
    var html = document.documentElement;
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var scrollHeight = body.scrollHeight;
    root = (document.compatMode.indexOf('CSS') >= 0) ? html : body;
    activeElement = body;
    initTest();
    initDone = true;
    if (top != self) {
      isFrame = true;
    } else if (scrollHeight > windowHeight && (body.offsetHeight <= windowHeight || html.offsetHeight <= windowHeight)) {
      var pending = false;
      var refresh = function() {
        if (!pending && html.scrollHeight != document.height) {
          pending = true;
          setTimeout(function() {
            html.style.height = document.height + 'px';
            pending = false;
          }, 500);
        }
      };
      html.style.height = 'auto';
      setTimeout(refresh, 10);
      if (root.offsetHeight <= windowHeight) {
        var underlay = document.createElement("div");
        underlay.style.clear = "both";
        body.appendChild(underlay);
      }
    }
    if (!options.fixedBackground && !isExcluded) {
      body.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll";
      html.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll";
    }
  }
  var que = [];
  var pending = false;
  var lastScroll = +new Date();

  function scrollArray(elem, left, top, delay) {
    if (delay === undefined) {
      delay = 1000;
    }
    directionCheck(left, top);
    if (options.accelerationMax != 1) {
      var now = +new Date();
      var elapsed = now - lastScroll;
      if (elapsed < options.accelerationDelta) {
        var factor = (1 + (30 / elapsed)) / 2;
        if (factor > 1) {
          factor = Math.min(factor, options.accelerationMax);
          left *= factor;
          top *= factor;
        }
      }
      lastScroll = +new Date();
    }
    que.push({
      x: left,
      y: top,
      lastX: (left < 0) ? 0.99 : -0.99,
      lastY: (top < 0) ? 0.99 : -0.99,
      start: +new Date()
    });
    if (pending) {
      return;
    }
    var scrollWindow = (elem === document.body);
    var step = function(time) {
      var now = +new Date();
      var scrollX = 0;
      var scrollY = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < que.length; i++) {
        var item = que[i];
        var elapsed = now - item.start;
        var finished = (elapsed >= options.animationTime);
        var position = (finished) ? 1 : elapsed / options.animationTime;
        if (options.pulseAlgorithm) {
          position = pulse(position);
        }
        var x = (item.x * position - item.lastX) >> 0;
        var y = (item.y * position - item.lastY) >> 0;
        scrollX += x;
        scrollY += y;
        item.lastX += x;
        item.lastY += y;
        if (finished) {
          que.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      }
      if (scrollWindow) {
        window.scrollBy(scrollX, scrollY);
      } else {
        if (scrollX)
          elem.scrollLeft += scrollX;
        if (scrollY)
          elem.scrollTop += scrollY;
      }
      if (!left && !top) {
        que = [];
      }
      if (que.length) {
        requestFrame(step, elem, (delay / options.frameRate + 1));
      } else {
        pending = false;
      }
    };
    requestFrame(step, elem, 0);
    pending = true;
  }

  function wheel(event) {
    if (!initDone) {
      init();
    }
    var target = event.target;
    var overflowing = overflowingAncestor(target);
    if (!overflowing || event.defaultPrevented || isNodeName(activeElement, "embed") || (isNodeName(target, "embed") && /\.pdf/i.test(target.src))) {
      return true;
    }
    var deltaX = event.wheelDeltaX || 0;
    var deltaY = event.wheelDeltaY || 0;
    if (!deltaX && !deltaY) {
      deltaY = event.wheelDelta || 0;
    }
    if (!options.touchpadSupport && isTouchpad(deltaY)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > 1.2) {
      deltaX *= options.stepSize / 120;
    }
    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > 1.2) {
      deltaY *= options.stepSize / 120;
    }
    scrollArray(overflowing, -deltaX, -deltaY);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function keydown(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    var modifier = event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.metaKey || (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode !== key.spacebar);
    if (/input|textarea|select|embed/i.test(target.nodeName) || target.isContentEditable || event.defaultPrevented || modifier) {
      return true;
    }
    if (isNodeName(target, "button") && event.keyCode === key.spacebar) {
      return true;
    }
    var shift, x = 0,
      y = 0;
    var elem = overflowingAncestor(activeElement);
    var clientHeight = elem.clientHeight;
    if (elem == document.body) {
      clientHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case key.up:
        y = -options.arrowScroll;
        break;
      case key.down:
        y = options.arrowScroll;
        break;
      case key.spacebar:
        shift = event.shiftKey ? 1 : -1;
        y = -shift * clientHeight * 0.9;
        break;
      case key.pageup:
        y = -clientHeight * 0.9;
        break;
      case key.pagedown:
        y = clientHeight * 0.9;
        break;
      case key.home:
        y = -elem.scrollTop;
        break;
      case key.end:
        var damt = elem.scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop - clientHeight;
        y = (damt > 0) ? damt + 10 : 0;
        break;
      case key.left:
        x = -options.arrowScroll;
        break;
      case key.right:
        x = options.arrowScroll;
        break;
      default:
        return true;
    }
    scrollArray(elem, x, y);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function mousedown(event) {
    activeElement = event.target;
  }
  var cache = {};
  setInterval(function() {
    cache = {};
  }, 10 * 1000);
  var uniqueID = (function() {
    var i = 0;
    return function(el) {
      return el.uniqueID || (el.uniqueID = i++);
    };
  })();

  function setCache(elems, overflowing) {
    for (var i = elems.length; i--;)
      cache[uniqueID(elems[i])] = overflowing;
    return overflowing;
  }

  function overflowingAncestor(el) {
    var elems = [];
    var rootScrollHeight = root.scrollHeight;
    do {
      var cached = cache[uniqueID(el)];
      if (cached) {
        return setCache(elems, cached);
      }
      elems.push(el);
      if (rootScrollHeight === el.scrollHeight) {
        if (!isFrame || root.clientHeight + 10 < rootScrollHeight) {
          return setCache(elems, document.body);
        }
      } else if (el.clientHeight + 10 < el.scrollHeight) {
        overflow = getComputedStyle(el, "").getPropertyValue("overflow-y");
        if (overflow === "scroll" || overflow === "auto") {
          return setCache(elems, el);
        }
      }
    } while (el = el.parentNode);
  }

  function addEvent(type, fn, bubble) {
    window.addEventListener(type, fn, (bubble || false));
  }

  function removeEvent(type, fn, bubble) {
    window.removeEventListener(type, fn, (bubble || false));
  }

  function isNodeName(el, tag) {
    return (el.nodeName || "").toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase();
  }

  function directionCheck(x, y) {
    x = (x > 0) ? 1 : -1;
    y = (y > 0) ? 1 : -1;
    if (direction.x !== x || direction.y !== y) {
      direction.x = x;
      direction.y = y;
      que = [];
      lastScroll = 0;
    }
  }
  var deltaBufferTimer;

  function isTouchpad(deltaY) {
    if (!deltaY)
      return;
    deltaY = Math.abs(deltaY);
    deltaBuffer.push(deltaY);
    deltaBuffer.shift();
    clearTimeout(deltaBufferTimer);
    var allDivisable = (isDivisible(deltaBuffer[0], 120) && isDivisible(deltaBuffer[1], 120) && isDivisible(deltaBuffer[2], 120));
    return !allDivisable;
  }

  function isDivisible(n, divisor) {
    return (Math.floor(n / divisor) == n / divisor);
  }
  var requestFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback, element, delay) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, delay || (1000 / 60));
    };
  })();

  function pulse_(x) {
    var val, start, expx;
    x = x * options.pulseScale;
    if (x < 1) {
      val = x - (1 - Math.exp(-x));
    } else {
      start = Math.exp(-1);
      x -= 1;
      expx = 1 - Math.exp(-x);
      val = start + (expx * (1 - start));
    }
    return val * options.pulseNormalize;
  }

  function pulse(x) {
    if (x >= 1)
      return 1;
    if (x <= 0)
      return 0;
    if (options.pulseNormalize == 1) {
      options.pulseNormalize /= pulse_(1);
    }
    return pulse_(x);
  }
  var isChrome = /chrome/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
  var wheelEvent = null;
  if ("onwheel" in document.createElement("div"))
    wheelEvent = "wheel";
  else if ("onmousewheel" in document.createElement("div"))
    wheelEvent = "mousewheel";
  if (wheelEvent && isChrome) {
    addEvent(wheelEvent, wheel);
    addEvent("mousedown", mousedown);
    addEvent("load", init);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Why would replacing `=` by `==` fix it? You _do_ need an assignment here. Idiomatically, this can be fixed by using a double set of parentheses: `while((el = el.parentNode))`.

Comment: @Xufox, which is only for linter, but it does not change the expression.

Comment: `Error` ... no `warning` really ... but to make linter happy `while ((el = el.parentNode))`

Comment: @Xufox, because it says that it expects an conditional expression instead of an assignment. I thought I could fix it by changing it to one by using `==`.

Comment: @Black - that would change the logic

Comment: @JaromandaX, But why is the error even showing then?

Comment: because a) it's **not** an error; and b) the reasons already given

Comment: @Black That’s a linter warning. Most of the time you want to compare in loop conditions rather than assign, and confusing `=` vs. `==` is a common beginner error, so linters assume that assignments are incorrect in loop conditions. Even people who read your code might get confused when they see an assignment in a loop condition, so it’s better to be more explicit with your intents to begin with.

Comment: But the assignment serves an important purpose, so you can't just replace it. Other than the solutions already offered, you could solve it by moving the assignment expression to the last line of the `while` block and then make the condition like this: `while (el);`

Comment: @MikaelLennholm - how is that "other than the solutions already offered" - that is exactly my solution :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't see your answer, I was only referring to what had been mentioned in the comments

Comment: @MikaelLennholm - I did put a :p after my comment - it's all good :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the linter happy, move the assignment to the line before `while` and then `while(el)`

```
do {
    // snip
    el = el.parentNode;
} while (el);
```

alternatively

```
do {
    // snip

} while ((el = el.parentNode));
```

not sure if all "linters" will play nice with this, but jshint usually does

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with tampermonkey, but from what you're describing it seems it's stricter than the JavaScript parser. Anyway, to understand why `while (el = el.parentNode)` works, there's two things you need to know.

(1) Conditions in JavaScript (those used in `if`, `while`, and the second expression of a conventional `for` loop) don't have to be strictly boolean expressions, such as `x == 1`. They can be any expression you like. JavaScript will evaluate that expression, and then decide if the result is "truthy" or "falsy" (those are actual words). A "falsy" value is `false`, `null`, `undefined`, 0, or an empty string. Any other value is "truthy" (including an empty array or an empty object). Truthy values means the `if` branch will be executed, or in your case, the loop will continue.

(2) Value assignments in JavaScript are an expression like any other, and expressions always have a result. In case of a value assignment, it's the value that was assigned. The fact that the variable on the left side ends up containing the assigned value is, strictly speaking, a "side effect".

With these two facts in mind, here's what happens in `while (el = el.parentNode)`:

1. The parser evaluates `el.parentNode`. This may be a node, or `null` if `el` does not have a parent (i.e. if it's the document itself).
2. The value of `el.parentNode` is assigned to `el`. The result of this operation of the value that was assigned.
3. This result is then evaluated to be truthy or falsy. If `el` did not have a parent, `el.parentNode` was `null`, which is a falsy value, so the loop stops. If it's not, the loop continues.

So, JavaScript allows variable assignments in conditions, but it seems tampermonkey does not. This is probably because 99% of the time you do want to use `==` in a condition, and it's very easy to accidentally type `=` instead of `==`. This can lead to a lot of frustration and hard-to-find bugs, since as discussed above, JavaScript will happily process it without errors, so a lot of linters will mark it as an error.

Also, `el == el.parentNode` doesn't make sense, because a node can never be equal to its parent.